# Error by using @ in PHP for Error Surpass

Tags: php, codeigniter, parsing-error

in my project old developer used @ at many places so now i have to upload project on server but at server @ does not support i dont why 
Porject is developed in codeigniter

```
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '@' in
A PHP Error was encountered
Severity: Parsing Error
Message: syntax error, unexpected '@'
```

Please guys guide me 
Thanks in Advance

Comment: What version of php?

Comment: So it is an real syntax error, because `@` before functions and variables are allowed in all php versions. Can you post full error message? Or better some of the code where the error shows up!?

Comment: we were using @ for error suppression but it works on local but not on server and i have post the error

Comment: Post the code that generates this error

Comment: Not with relevant infos. Please post some of the code that generates the error.

Comment: <?= @$userdata['social_facebook'] ?>

Comment: Maybe you have to allow short-open tag `<?=` in `php.ini`  or test `<?php @$userdata['social_facebook']; ?>` the `@` is not the error. http://php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.short-open-tag

Comment: Could you show us the code with the line where you got this error?

Comment: You don't need the @ sign. <?php echo $userdata['social_facebook']; ?>

Comment: Thanks it solved @JustOnUnderMillions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just update PHP version it will sort out